# GLM with proportion DV and categorical IV. Which Stata formula should I use?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, stata, proportion

I ran an experiment to see if a particular gamification design (2 treatment groups) would perform better in terms of quality than the control. The design was run on a reporting application where citizens can report issues in their environment to the government, and the government can act upon it.

Quality in my data is measured by the number of successful reports of an individual/total reports made of the same individual. (Successful reports are those acted on by the government.)

The data would look something like this, where each row represents 1 individual:

[image]

The Competition and Inter-Team represent the IV which is categorical; the baseline is no design. My question is which of the following commands in Stata should I use?:

**Approach 1**

```
glm Succesful_Report Competition Inter-Team, ///
family(binomial Total_Report) link(logit)    ///
vce(robust) nolog
```

Here the `binomial Total_Report` takes into account the fact that each individual has a different denominator (total number of reports). The fact that the individuals in the control report less would then be accounted for.

**Approach 2**

```
glm Proportion Competition Inter-Team,     ///
family(binomial) link(logit)               ///
vce(robust) nolog
```

In this case the proportion is directly taken as the DV.

I am unsure which approach to take to test whether the treatment group (Competition and Inter-Team) outperform the control in regard to the quality. What would be advised?

Comment: Please note that the correct spelling is Stata rather than STATA since it's not an acronym.

Comment: I've edited STATA to Stata, This was cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1502993-glm-with-proportion-dv-and-categorical-iv-which-stata-formula-should-i-use  It's always courteous to tell people about cross-posting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think either model is particularly appropriate since your treatment can alter the denominator of the rate/number of binomial trials. Approach 1 handles that in some sense, but the marginal effects it produces will be in terms of successful reports rather than in terms of an effect on a proportion. But what to do instead?

If I understood your problem correctly, you hope to increase successful reports with your treatment, so it seems easier to model those directly. However, the gamification treatment may also increase total reports, and many of the incremental reports could be of lower quality, which will create additional verification work for the government employees that you want to minimize. For the evaluation of the policy what matters is the net effect of these two changes.

I don't think a single model will be able to capture this tradeoff, and two separate-but-linked models might be better. I would suggest separate models for *successful* and *unsuccessful* reports. If the treatment gets you X additional good reports at a cost of Y bad ones, you have to use your domain expertise to decide if this is a good outcome. This also has the added benefit of including the data with zero total reports in the analysis.

Heres's a toy and non-sensical example where the high_match treatment increases age but reduces employ. Assuming the cost of reducing employ is 1/10 of the benefit of an extra age, then we can combine the weighted marginal effects from the two equation. Here we find that the combined effect is negative and significant, even with a steep discount of the employ lost. Here I used `suest` to combine the two models to facilitate testing across equations.

```
. webuse 401k, clear 

. gen high_match = mrate>0.5

. reg age i.high_match

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =     4,075
-------------+----------------------------------   F(1, 4073)      =    154.38
       Model |  12748.8181         1  12748.8181   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |   336361.44     4,073  82.5832162   R-squared       =    0.0365
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.0363
       Total |  349110.258     4,074  85.6922577   Root MSE        =    9.0875

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         age |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
1.high_match |    3.76075   .3026812    12.42   0.000      3.16733    4.354171
       _cons |   6.944302   .1739579    39.92   0.000     6.603249    7.285354
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. estimates store m1

. reg employ i.high_match

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =     4,075
-------------+----------------------------------   F(1, 4073)      =      6.89
       Model |   499692593         1   499692593   Prob > F        =    0.0087
    Residual |  2.9553e+11     4,073  72559000.4   R-squared       =    0.0017
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.0014
       Total |  2.9603e+11     4,074  72663844.2   Root MSE        =    8518.2

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      employ |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
1.high_match |   -744.545   283.7169    -2.62   0.009    -1300.785   -188.3049
       _cons |    2253.13   163.0587    13.82   0.000     1933.446    2572.814
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. estimates store m2

. suest m1 m2, robust // use coefl option to see the coefficient names

Simultaneous results for m1, m2

                                                Number of obs     =      4,075

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
             |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
m1_mean      |
1.high_match |    3.76075   .3266044    11.51   0.000     3.120617    4.400883
       _cons |   6.944302   .1593961    43.57   0.000     6.631891    7.256713
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
m1_lnvar     |
       _cons |   4.413806   .0352829   125.10   0.000     4.344653     4.48296
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
m2_mean      |
1.high_match |   -744.545   225.9892    -3.29   0.001    -1187.476   -301.6143
       _cons |    2253.13   189.8268    11.87   0.000     1881.076    2625.183
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
m2_lnvar     |
       _cons |   18.09991   .3430138    52.77   0.000     17.42762    18.77221
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. nlcom tradeoff:_b[m1_mean:1.high_match] + .1*_b[m2_mean:1.high_match]

    tradeoff:  _b[m1_mean:1.high_match] + .1*_b[m2_mean:1.high_match]

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    tradeoff |  -70.69375   22.65443    -3.12   0.002    -115.0956   -26.29189
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Stata Code:

```
cls
webuse 401k, clear 
gen high_match = mrate>0.5
reg age i.high_match
estimates store m1
reg employ i.high_match
estimates store m2
suest m1 m2, robust // use coefl option to see the coefficient names
nlcom tradeoff:_b[m1_mean:1.high_match] + .1*_b[m2_mean:1.high_match]
```

Comment: I think the OP wrote that quality is measured by the proprtion of successful reports, not number of successful reports.

Comment: @jsk I agree with your claim, but I tried to make the argument that the proportion is a problematic metric in the context of this experiment. I think there is real tradeoff between successful and unsuccessful reports and have proposed a solution. Moreover, the solution advocated on Statalist does not even produce estimates on the proportion scale. If there's a better approach in your eyes, please feel free to provide a second answer.

Comment: Not sure. Interesting question. I suppose it's always difficult in terms of whether you directly answer the posed question (Increased quality), or nudge toward a different evaluation metric that also takes into account the increased cost of processing additional reports as well.